# Making ASP.NET label visible appears to have no effect

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have the following in my code:

```
 lblIsInvalid.Visible = True
```

I have noticed that even after going to this line, it does not make the label visible.
I am thinking this may be a refresh issue as the last line hit is lblIsInvalid.Visible = True.
Is there any refresh property that I may not be aware of for a label control.

Comment: I'm assuming this is an ASP.NET project based on your other questions.  If not, please excuse my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a WinForm project, no, label visibility works the way you expect.  If you set it visible and it's not showing up, it's most likely because it's inside a container parent control which is not visible, or it's location is off the viewable area of the form, or it's behind another control, or something is setting it invisible again.